# Typescript with Api.AI in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, dialogflow-es

I'm having a trouble of importing my ApiAIPlugin inside Ionic 2 Angular 2 with Typescript app

I have added the plugin via ***ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-apiai*** comamnd it's inside config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-apiai" spec="~1.7.4"/>
```

but I don't know how to import it inside my home.ts file,
I have tried adding

```
declare var window: any
```

above my @Component({})
and trying to use it inside constructor like this:

```
window.plugins.ApiAIPlugin.init({...})
```

but both in the browser and in the emulator I get:
*Cannot read property 'ApiAIPlugin' of undefined...*

can someone help me?

p.s. used [this link](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-in-ionic-2-with-ionic-native/) to try the above mentioned things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ApiAIPlugin` is your global object for the plugin.
You should declare the global object directly.

```
declare var ApiAIPlugin:any;
```

and use

```
ApiAIPlugin.init({...})
```

Or try

```
 declare var window:any;
```

and:

```
window.ApiAIPlugin.init({})
```

Comment: neither works in the browser, should I bother trying the emulator? and thanks for the quick response

Comment: Yes!!.. cordova dont work in browser.. plugins dont work with 'ionic serve`. You need emulator/device

Comment: The first option does not throw the error in the emulator, thanks @suraj

Comment: @suraj - not working work either ways you described see issue raised on https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-cordova-client/issues/29

Comment: @SunilKumar there is another issue raised https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-cordova-client/issues/28 which has this linked : https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-javascript-client#typescript-and-es6 maybe try that

Comment: @SunilKumar it could have changed for later versions of ionic 2 and 3

Comment: @suraj - That one #28 is for javascript sdk your answer only works for javascript integration and not for native

Comment: OK.. I guess you will have to wait for the response in github..  As I said things may have changed in newer versions of ionic..  Direct use of cordova plugins were working...